# error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from

Tags: c++, sqlite, unicode, char, stringstream

While using SQLite in C++98, how to convert `stringstream` to Unicode and pass it to `sqlite3_exec()`? I constantly have this error:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>        with"
```

Code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;
    char *sql;
    const char* data = "Callback function called";
    tstringstream tstrsSQL;
    tstrsSQL.imbue(std::locale("C"));

    std::string s = tstrsSQL.str(); // converting stringstream to char?
    const char* p = s.c_str();

    /* Open database */
    rc = sqlite3_open("db.db3", &db);

    if( rc ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        return(0);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
    }

    /* Create SQL statement */
    tstrsSQL << _T("SELECT") something ("FROM") << table;

    /* Execute SQL statement */
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, p, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg); // p needs to be unicode
```

Comment: You need to copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output and show us. Also please point out on which line in the code you show the error is (by adding a comment on the line).

Comment: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=wchar_t,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<wchar_t>,
1>            _Ax=std::allocator<wchar_t>
1>        ]
1>        and
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>            _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>        ]
1>        No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

Comment: If you are using Unicode **don't** use string or char, always use tstring and TCHAR. Also define UNICODE. Also use _T("") instead of "" **everywhere**. All you need to do is be consistent.

Comment: Do you really mean Unicode? Or do you mean wide C-strings? You are probably using Windows and confusing "Unicode" with "UTF-16", then confusing encodings with types.

Comment: I've set tstrsSQL.imbue(std::locale("C"));

Comment: just change `tstringstream` to `stringstream`.

Comment: Nope, still same problem. Also this is defined typedef std::wstringstream tstringstream; I've changed everything from tstringstream to stringstream and still the same error.

Comment: @john - I agree "be consistent", but I strongly disagree "use tstring and TCHAR", They only make sense *if* (like Windows itself) you need to support both Unicode and Ansi builds.  The rest of us should *only* use Unicode builds, and write `wstring` and `wchar_t` (and prefix string literals with `L` of course).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You've lost that battle.  On Window "Unicode" means something slightly different, there's no point arguing "it shouldn't" - it does.

Comment: @MartinBonner I agree and almost no-one these days needs to support unicode and ansi, but the OP has already started down the TCHAR path, and is likely reading something online which uses TCHAR. Anyone starting afresh should use wchar_t and wstring, or char16_t and u16string.

Comment: Hmm, I see from the answer below that I'm wrong.

Comment: @john All the MS documentation is in terms of TCHAR et al - the community should push the point that this is a documentation convenience, and should be read as wchar_t et al. (Or equivalent.)

Comment: @MartinBonner Nah honestly I'm with you on that - I don't and won't try to fight it. _But_ I do try to ensure that affected individuals are at least aware of what the terms mean elsewhere because it can be important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `tstringstream`, which I guess uses `std::wstringstream` if `UNICODE` is defined, so its `str()` gives a `std::basic_string<wchar_t>`.

But you get the result into a `std::string`, which is `std::basic_string<char>`. So the assignment fails.

Anyway, you take the result and use it in `sqlite3_exec()`, which takes a `const char*` as input.

That's why you shouldn't use `tstringstream`, you should use `std::stringstream`, and remove the `_T` from all of the string literals.

#### Minimal, complete, working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stringstream strstream;
    strstream << "Hello World";
    string str = strstream.str();
    cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```